# Finite unit regular rings that have proper ideals

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unit.  $a\in R$ is called unit regular if there exists a unit $u\in R$
such that $a=aua$. A ring is called unit regular if every element of $R$ is unit regular.   Examples of unit regular rings include division rings, boolean rings and strongly regular (von Newmann) ring.   Finite unit regular rings include $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $p$ is prime and these have no proper ideals.

Question:  Are there examples of finite unit regular rings that have proper ideals?

Comment: It is written *Neumann* and pronounced roughly  *noy-man* and “Newmann” never enters into it.

Comment: Noted with thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example $F_2\times F_2$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.

Any finite, nonsimple semisimple ring is an example.  So a product of multiple matrix rings of any size over any finite field is going to be an example.